# How to fix intermittent connection problems on Epoptes

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, ltsp

I have been using Epoptes on an Ubuntu 16.04 server to monitor my computer lab for about a year, it worked fine until I updated the clients from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.

Now the client connects to the Epoptes server when it first signs in but then disconnects within a few seconds. Clients then appear sporadically for a few seconds, then disappear again.

There seems to be a problem connecting to the server:

```
    $ sudo epoptes-client -c
140226841174464:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:108:
140226841174464:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:109:
connect:errno=111
epoptes-client ERROR: Failed to fetch certificate from server:789
```

I nearly always get this when I try to connect from the client to the Epoptes server to get a certificate.

Very rarely it works, especially if I disconnect the server from the network then reconnect. I then get this:

```
    $ sudo epoptes-client -c
depth=0 C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = AU, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
verify return:1
DONE
Successfully fetched certificate from server:789
```

Can anyone help me work out what is going on?

In the meantime, I am re-installing 16.04 on the server and making a fresh install of Pinet, including Epoptes. Maybe I have switched to 18.04 too early.

Comment: For me it seems that you can get better results by contacting [Alkis Georgopoulos](https://launchpad.net/~alkisg) or filing bug against Epoptes. I'm running LTSP with Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS (with Epoptes on server and epoptes-client on clients), and not yet tested 18.04 LTS.